# Bootstrap modal doesn't load properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm Creating a website in ASP.NET (Framework 4.0).

A Master page has required bootstrap files & jquery files are added in it.
files are as

```
 <link href="../assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../Styles/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Styles/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Bootstrap modal doesn't work properly on button Click.

[image: Bootstrap Modal]

On child page button click this should work.

child page code. (page1.aspx.cs)

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   lblModal2.Text = "Please Add Item To Cart";
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "warning","$('#warning').modal();", true);
}
```

child page (page1.aspx) Bootstrap modal code as follows.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="warning" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header modal-header-warning">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                        ×</button>
                    <h1>
                        <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>Warning
                    </h1>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblModal2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">
                        Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>
```

Comment: `$("#warning").modal("show"); ` should be the correct code.

Comment: @Hemal added your code in ScriptManager gives error.

Comment: Can you describe how its not working correctly right now and how it is supposed to work?

Comment: The Bootstrap Modal is behind the black transparent layer as given in above image . But it should be above the black transparent layer

Comment: **As per your code**  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "warning", "$('#warning').modal("show");", true); gives error

Comment: Some other element might have z-index higher than bootstrap modal. Try setting z-index of bootstrap modal to highest value or lower z-index of other element.

Comment: @Hemal i have set z-index to -1

Comment: Try setting z-index of modal to 10000. Might be `.modal {
  z-index: 10000;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this code line in css file.

```
.modal-backdrop {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `$('#warning').appendTo("show")` and replace it with

```
$('#warning').appendTo("body") ;
```

Comment: Syntax is correct , when i remove ("body") all errors are gone. And keeps like this $('#warning').appendTo() ; all errors are gone

Comment: There might be some error on your HTML page, either in HTML or Script, might be missing some closing tags or closing brackets.

Comment: script as follows: `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "warning", "$('#warning').appendTo("body");", true);`  .Gives error  ) expected

Comment: Put single quotes around `body`.`$('#warning').appendTo('body') ;`